# update image didn't display in gridview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I have been created student details form by using aspx and c#.

In the image field i got some error.

What i have done:

Insert,edit and update image.

When i insert image and submit, I was set to display that image in gridview on the same page, and also save in "images" folder in my drive.

It works fine, but when i edit the image and upload new image and submit, the changed image didn't show in the gridview, but this changed image saved in "images" folder.

May i know, what is my mistake in my code?

Here is my source code:

```
protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            if (Textid.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_updatestudentdetail", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
try
                {
                    string filename = Image1.ImageUrl.Substring(Image1.ImageUrl.IndexOf('/')+1);
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images"));
                    string uniqueFileName = string.Empty;                                    
                    if (fileupload.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (string f in files) File.Delete(f);    
                        filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower();
                        uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtension;
                        fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + uniqueFileName));                 
                    }

                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", (filename.Length > 0) ? "Images/" + filename : (uniqueFileName.Length > 0) ? "Images/" + uniqueFileName : string.Empty);
                        com.ExecuteNonQuery();   
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    btnsub.Text = ex.Message;
                }                  
}



 else
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_insertstudentdetail", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 try
                {
                    string filename = string.Empty;
                    string uniqueFileName = string.Empty;
                    if (fileupload.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
                    {
                        filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower();
                        uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtension;
                        fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + uniqueFileName));
                    }                        

                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", (filename.Length > 0) ? "Images/" + uniqueFileName : string.Empty);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    btnsub.Text = ex.Message;
                }
}
}
```

Here is editrow:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();

            if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
            { 
                Image1.ImageUrl = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)gr.Cells[7].Controls[0]).ImageUrl;
}
}
```

and here is my output of my screenshot:

http://s3.postimg.org/bpgzjlmub/untitled.jpg

Can anyone help me to fix my issue, I'm new to .net.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The gridview in asp.net does not automatically update itself. You need to again bind the gridview. What you need to do is put the code of binding the grid in one function say `bindgrid()` something like this.

```
public void bindgrid()
{
            con = new SqlConnection(connStr);  
            con.Open();  
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Grid_Data", con);  
            Dataset ds = new DataSet();  
            da.Fill(ds);  
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;  
            GridView1.DataBind();  

}
```

and then call `bindgrid()` after every insert and update performed in grid. If this doesn't work out, I might need to see your binding logic.
Thank you

Comment: I actually, new to .net.. so can you please help in code?

Comment: @Rani  check my answer again, i have put example code in it

Comment: @ Maulik Modi: i already select query in this sp_updatestudentdetail right?

Comment: no you have to call bindgrid() at the end of it. have a look at this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/77a82c/binding-image-with-gridview-and-update-image-in-gridview/

Comment: hi.. can you please edit my code? show me exactly? because i'm new .. i'm struggling where i can edit my code.. thanks..

Comment: Share me the fiddle of both aspx and aspx.cs